# How to export a nested dictionary into a csv and format it into columns and rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to search for my problem, but I couldn't find anything closley related, so I decided to put my question in here. I'm pretty new to Python and still learning this languange, so forgive me if I didn't catch obvious things.

Currently I'm trying to extract data via beautifulsoup from some letters that were transformed into .xml-files. Those extracted data - I put them into a nested dictionary. What I want to accomplish is a csv-file which contains all those data.

I've got a nested dictionary like this:

```
dict = [
 {"id":"0", "foundPersons" : ["Smith, Bernhard","Jackson, Andrew","Dalton, Henry"], "sendfrom" : "Calahan, Agnes"}, 
 {"id":"1", "foundPersons" : ["Cutter, John","Ryan, Jack"], "sendfrom" : "Enrico, Giovanni"}
 {"id":"2", "foundPersons" : "Grady, Horace", "sendfrom" : "Calahan, Agnes"}
]
```

I want to have ID, foundPersons and sendfrom als the header of each column. Then below the ID header I want to have every ID in each cell, every foundPerson of one ID into one cell (that means that those 3 names of ID0 are in one cell) and so on.

I tried that by using the csv module but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish that. Can somebody maybe give me a hint? Or is there any other module / library which can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the pandas library here.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
data.to_csv('output.csv')

print(data)
```

And your data is now organized to columns and rows.

Comment: Thank you! But while in the notebook it looks organized, it still isn't inside the csv. It's split into rows for each entry of the dictionary, but not into colums.

Comment: I tried it with Excel 2016, so that's strange. When I open the file with notepad, it contains this: ,foundPersons,id,sendfrom [BREAKLINE]
0,"['Smith, Bernhard', 'Jackson, Andrew', 'Dalton, Henry']",0,"Calahan, Agnes"[BREAKLINE]
1,"['Cutter, John', 'Ryan, Jack']",1,"Enrico, Giovanni"[BREAKLINE]
2,"Grady, Horace",2,"Calahan, Agnes"[BREAKLINE]

It's all in one column. But when I change the comma between the data into a semicolon, Excel splits it into colums. Strange, I will try another version of Excel

Comment: I tried it with LibreOffice where it worked fine. Thank you very much! You helpled me a lot! Have a great weekend